# components props are empty even after successful promise callback - angular tests

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I've been trying for the past two days to identify the issue for an angular test that is failing constantly. On a `Promise` callback the component props are set but when `spying` over the same `Promise` success callback, the props aren't updated neither the logs are consoled in the browser. e.g the following test passes and props are updated without any issue:

```
fit('should call insuranceSerivce.search', () => {
    component.travelPeriod = ['01-08-2019', '01-08-09'];
    component.destination = 'MYS';
    component.tripType.individual = 'days';
    component.onContinue();

    expect(insuranceServiceSpy.search).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However the following test fails If I uncomment the `plans` prop expectation

```
fit('should send the success response to "onSearchInsuranceSuccess"', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onSearchInsuranceSuccess');

    component.travelPeriod = ['01-08-2019', '01-08-09'];
    component.destination = 'MYS';
    component.tripType.individual = 'days';
    component.onContinue();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick();

    expect(component.onSearchInsuranceSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log('[[[plans at spec]]]', component.plans); // Why is it always empty?
    // expect(component.plans[0].plan).toEqual(insurance.data[0].plan); <-- it fails here
    // expect(component.benefitsList[0].title).toEqual(insurance.benefits[0].title);
}));
```

Another issue with the above test is if I place `fixture.detectChanges();` after `tick` it would throw the following error

> Error: 2 timer(s) still in the queue.

Following is the `component.ts` code:

```
    onContinue() {
        const startD = moment(this.travelPeriod[0], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
        const endD = moment(this.travelPeriod[1], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
        // The difference is +1 e.g 23-01-2012 till 23-01-2012 with diff 0 whilst we need 1 day insurance so 0 + 1 = 1;
        const duration = endD.diff(startD, 'days') + 1;
        const country = this.countriesList.find((co) => co.code === this.destination);
        const params = {
            plan: this.tripType,
            destination: this.destination,
            region: country.region,
            duration
        };
        console.log('[[plan before]]', this.plans);
        this.insuranceService.search(params)
        .then(
            (res: InsuranceSearchResponse) => this.onSearchInsuranceSuccess(res),
            (error) => this.onFailed(error)
            );
    }
    /**
     * when search insurance is successful
     */
    onSearchInsuranceSuccess(res: InsuranceSearchResponse) {
        if (res.success) {
            this.showForm = false;
            this.plans = res.data;
            this.benefitsList = res.benefits;
        } else {
            this.message = res.message;
        }
        console.log('[[plan after]]', this.plans);
    }
```

Following is the output of the `spec`

```
[[plan before]] []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
context.js:255 [[plan after]] (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {plan: "Plan 1", fare: {…}, details: {…}, supplierID: 17}1: {plan: "Plan 2", fare: {…}, details: {…}, supplierID: 17}2: {plan: "Plan 3", fare: {…}, details: {…}, supplierID: 17}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
context.js:255 [[plan before]] []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
context.js:255 [[[plans at spec]]] []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

and a [snapshot](https://ibb.co/NLf913P) of the above `console` output.

[insurance.component.spec.ts](https://kopy.io/gFofy)

Thanks

Comment: The issue is probably the ```spyOn``` call. Per default you create a stub which does nothing. So in your case spying on ```onSearchInsuranceSuccess``` stops the execution of whatever is inside but lets you test if the method was executed. If you want to spy and just let the rest execute you have to setup the spy with ```spyOn(...).and.callThrough()```. If you want to call some test method you could use callFake(). But in your case you do want the method just to do what it usually does I suppose. So callThrough would be the one to take.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig that's really awesome. would you please post your comment as an answer so I can go ahead and accept that? Also what was causing `Error: 2 timer(s) still in the queue.` this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably the spyOn call. Per default you create with this a stub which does nothing.

So in your case spying on `onSearchInsuranceSuccess` stops the execution of whatever is inside but lets you test if the method was executed.

There are methods which let you define what the spy should be doing. Usually that are things like `spyOn(...).and.returnValue` for example. If you want the spy to just execute what it normally does, you have to setup the spy with `spyOn(...).and.callThrough()`.

[Here is the offical jasmine documentation to the SpyStrategy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/SpyStrategy.html) showing all the available methods for your spy.

Comment: Would you please also add some comments regarding `Error: 2 timer(s) still in the queue` issue?

Comment: This error has usually something to do that not all the async code has been finished. But to actually help there I would need a stackblitz which recreates your error. Otherwise it's just guessing which observables are still in the queue.

Comment: Since there are no observable and only a single `Promise` that's defined inside `spec`

Comment: Sorry ment promises. there is one inside your beforeEach as well. I would need to know where it is actually used inside the component etc. So without seeing how the component and the test setup works together it is hard to tell you where the problem is.